# julia plot not working with float64 vectors

Tags: julia, julia-plots

I'm trying to plot 2 series, a training set and a testing set with plots:

```
xp = append!(XTrain.humidity, data.humidity)
yp = append!(YTrain, predictions)
println(length(xp))
println(length(yp))
Plots.plot(x=xp, y=yp,seriestype=:scatter)
```

this outputs

```
382
382
```

which is the expected result, with both xp and yp being a vector of floats

```
xp = [82.00274423, 80.31964408, 82.3207629, 83.37011772, 82.63941394, 82.894086...]
yp = [49.027397, 49.027397, 49.027397, 49.027397 ...]
```

But the plot in the output looks like this:
[image: not points]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting this plot because there's nothing to plot. `Plots.plot` is [supposed to be called](https://docs.juliaplots.org/stable/basics/) like this, with the data to plot being passed as *positional* arguments:

```
Plots.plot(xp, yp, seriestype=:scatter)
```

AFAIK, keyword arguments are for customizing the plot (like setting series type), not for passing data to plot.